# Save a number with line edit in Qt

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I want to save a number with a QLineEdit that is hidden from the users. I just want to use it for my programing.

In the Visual Basic 6 we have "Tag" property with textbox that can save any value in it as a temporary value.

Answer (score 3):

`QLineEdit` is a `QWidget` which is a `QObject`. Every `QObject` has the ability to store custom properties. It's worth checking the `QObject` documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html).

You can set custom properties with:

```
bool QObject::setProperty(const char* name, const QVariant& value)
```

and you can access custom properties with:

```
QVariant QObject::property(const char* name) const
```

Note that they store the data as `QVariant`s, so your type must be registered as a metatype via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType` unless it's one of the built-in metatypes.

Though, honestly, I've never used dynamic properties like that. I usually find it simpler to store the widget and its related data side by side as normal variables.

Answer (score -1):

you can use setData method to attach data to most QT objects.

Comment: setData is a method on QGraphicsItem. It doesn't exist on QLineEdit, though setProperty is very similar.